# Combinations with guaranteed membership of an element

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I would like to calculate/enumerate a subset of combinations of a set.

More specifically assuming a set $n$, where n={a,b,c,d}, I would like only those combinations of length k=2, such that some membership criterion is met (for example, I would like all combinations of length k=2 that include $b$)

so if NchooseK(n,2)={{a,b},{a,c},{a,d},{b,c},{b,d},{c,d}}, what I would really need is only the subset X of NchooseK, where X={{a,b},{b,c},{b,d}}.

Is there a formula that returns X in combinatorics? Alternatively, if I cannot define them, can I at least count how many they are?

So, can I say for example that if n has 4 items and I am only interested in pairs, how many pairs will always contain one item of the 4?

In my example I can say that only 3 of 6 will meet my constraint, and I can also tell which 3.

Comment: If you have $n$ distinct elements of a set $\{a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n\}$ and you want to count the pairs that contains $a_k$, where $1 \leq k \leq n$, it is trivial to point out that they are exactly $n-1$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the following way:
let k mean the number of elements you want to selent and n all the elements.
You know you want b in the set. So you have to choose another k-1 elements from the remaining n-1 elements and you can do this in $\binom{n-1}{k-1} = \frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}$ ways.